# Can LSTMBlockFusedCell have 6% higher (test) error than LSTMCell or Did I make mistakes on dropout?

Tags: tensorflow

I built a simple stacked dynamic bidirectional LSTM with `LSTMCell`, `DropoutWrapper`, `MultiRNNCell`, and `bidirectional_dynamic_rnn` (**Model_Orig**) for a regression problem. The test absolute error after 20 epochs is 2.89 and the training time is 14.5 hours.

Then I tried an alternative implementation (**Model_blockfused**), which has the same structure but uses the blockfused components (i.e. `tf.layers.dropout`, `LSTMBlockFusedCell`,  `TimeReversedFusedRNN`). The training time is much shorter for **Model_blockfused** (3.6 hours), but the test absolute error after 20 epochs is about 6% higher (3.06).

So, should I expect a 6% difference in performance between `LSTMBlockFusedCell` and `LSTMCell`? or Did I make any mistakes (especially for the dropout) when building **Model_blockfused**?

Here is the simplified code for **Model_Orig**:

```
LSTM_CELL_SIZE = 200
keep_prob = 0.90
parallel_iterations = 512

dropcells = []
for iiLyr in list(range(3)):
    cell_iiLyr = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=LSTM_CELL_SIZE, state_is_tuple=True)
    dropcells.append(tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell=cell_iiLyr, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)) 

MultiLyr_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells=dropcells, state_is_tuple=True)

outputs, states = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
    cell_fw=MultiLyr_cell, 
    cell_bw=MultiLyr_cell, 
    inputs=Orig_input_TSs, #shape of Orig_input_TSs: [#batches, time_len, #input_features]
    dtype=tf.float32,
    sequence_length=length, # shape of length: [#batches, 1]
    parallel_iterations = parallel_iterations, # default:32,  Those operations which do not have any temporal dependency and can be run in parallel, will be.
    scope = "BiLSTM"
    )

states_fw, states_bw = states

# get the states (c and h, both directions) from the top LSTM layer for final fully connected layers.
c_fw_lstLyr, h_fw_lstLyr = states_fw[-1]
c_bw_lstLyr, h_bw_lstLyr = states_bw[-1]
```

Here is the simplified code for **Model_blockfused**:

```
LSTM_CELL_SIZE = 200
keep_prob = 0.90
Flg_training = True # True: training

# convert the input sequences (Orig_input_TSs) to the time major format
# shape of input_TSs_TimeMajor: [time_len, #batches, #input_features]
input_TSs_TimeMajor = tf.transpose(Orig_input_TSs, perm=[1,0,2])

# apply the dropout
# shape of dropout_input_TSs_TimeMajor: [time_len, #batches, #input_features]
dropout_input_TSs_TimeMajor = tf.layers.dropout(
    input_TSs_TimeMajor,
    rate=1.0 - keep_prob, # dropout rate
    training=Flg_training
)

# build the stacked dynamic bidirectional LSTM
for iiLyr in list(range(3)):
    cur_fw_BFcell_obj = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockFusedCell(num_units=LSTM_CELL_SIZE)
    cur_bw_BFcell_obj = tf.contrib.rnn.TimeReversedFusedRNN(cur_fw_BFcell_obj)

    if (iiLyr == 0):
        # first layer (different inputs)
        # shape of fw_out_TM (or bw_out_TM): [time_len, #batches, LSTM_CELL_SIZE]
        # fw_state (or bw_state): LSTMStateTuple(c, h))
        fw_out_TM, fw_state = cur_fw_BFcell_obj(dropout_input_TSs_TimeMajor, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=length)
        bw_out_TM, bw_state = cur_bw_BFcell_obj(dropout_input_TSs_TimeMajor, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=length)
    else:
        # shape of fw_out_TM (or bw_out_TM): [time_len, #batches, LSTM_CELL_SIZE]
        # fw_state (or bw_state): LSTMStateTuple(c, h))
        fw_out_TM, fw_state = cur_fw_BFcell_obj(fw_out_TM, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=length)
        bw_out_TM, bw_state = cur_bw_BFcell_obj(bw_out_TM, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=length)

# get the LSTM states (c and h, both directions) from the top LSTM layer for final fully connected layers.
c_fw_lstLyr, h_fw_lstLyr = fw_state
c_bw_lstLyr, h_bw_lstLyr = bw_state
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

first，you should use two independent tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockFusedCell for fw and bw, change the code below

```
cur_fw_BFcell_obj = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockFusedCell(num_units=LSTM_CELL_SIZE)
cur_bw_BFcell_obj = tf.contrib.rnn.TimeReversedFusedRNN(cur_fw_BFcell_obj)
```

to this:

```
cur_fw_BFcell_obj = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockFusedCell(num_units=LSTM_CELL_SIZE)
cur_bw_BFcell_obj_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockFusedCell(num_units=LSTM_CELL_SIZE)
cur_bw_BFcell_obj = tf.contrib.rnn.TimeReversedFusedRNN(cur_bw_BFcell_obj_cell)
```

second,in tf's [tf.contrib.rnn.stack_bidirectional_dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.10/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/stack_bidirectional_dynamic_rnn) api, it says

> The combined forward and backward layer outputs are used as input of
>   the next layer.

so the code below

```
fw_out_TM, fw_state = cur_fw_BFcell_obj(fw_out_TM, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=length)
bw_out_TM, bw_state = cur_bw_BFcell_obj(bw_out_TM, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=length)
```

should be change to:

```
next_layer_input = tf.concat([fw_out_TM, bw_out_TM], axis=2)
fw_out_TM, fw_state = cur_fw_BFcell_obj(next_layer_input, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=length)
bw_out_TM, bw_state = cur_bw_BFcell_obj(next_layer_input, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=length)
```